# Positive definiteness of a matrix-valued function

Tags: stochastic-processes, covariance, positive-definite

> Are there simple conditions on an $d \times d$  matrix B under which
> $$ f(t, s) = \exp(—B |t — s|^\alpha), \qquad \alpha \in (0, 2), \qquad t, \, s \in \mathbb{R}$$
> is positive definite as a matrix-valued function *(see def below)*?

Is it true in general that if $r(t, s)$ is a positive definite **matrix-valued** function, then so is $\exp(r(t, s))$? This is obviously true if $r$ is scalar valued.

The reason for this particular question is that I am interested in the corresponding class of multivariate fractional Ornstein-Uhlenbeck processes.

---

P.S. By positive definiteness I mean
$$
\sum_{i, j} \mathbf{x}_i^\top f (t_i, t_j) \, \mathbf{x}_j \geq 0
\qquad \forall \, t_i \in \mathbb{R}, \quad \mathbf{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^d.
$$

Comment: Could you edit your post to explain why you are interested in this particular function?

Comment: @FD_bfa, I am interested in the corresponding class of multivariate fractional Ornstein-Uhlenbeck processes.

Comment: Please confirm that your indices $s,t$ are in integer interval $[1,n]$ (not $[0,n-1]$).

Comment: Your "definition" of positive definiteness is extremely strange and nonstandard. A real matrix $A$ is pos. def. if for all nonzero real vectors $u$ we have $u^\intercal Au >0$.

Comment: @K.defaoite, because it's not a definition of a positive definite matrix. It's a definition of a positive definite matrix-valued function. You can check any book on multivariate Gaussian processes to learn that this is a criterion for being a covariance of a multivariate process.

Comment: @K.defaoite, but, say, $f(t, t)$ is positive definite as a matrix for any $t$, this is true.